# Why won't my Raspberry Pi connect to Google Cloud IoT?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, mqtt, google-cloud-iot

I've added my `rsa_private.pem` in a certs directory of my project and added the corresponding `rsa_cert.pem` public key to my device in the IOT Core console.

I also ran `wget https://pki.google.com/roots.pem` from within the `certs` directory.

Something I don't understand is that the `roots.pem` file that got generated now has multiple -

```
----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
// RS256_X509 encoded cert here
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

with various `Operating CA:`s; `Comodo Group`, `GoDaddy`, `DigiCert`, `Entrust Datacard`, `GlobalSign` and `Google Trust Services LLC` which is what the original root.pem had when I first generated it.

I've tried adding the root.pem to `my-registry` in the console under `CA CERTIFICATES` but get an error that says `Certificate value is too big`
`

When I run `node gcloud.js` I either get `connecting...` followed by multiple `close` pings in the terminal if I include `protocolId: 'MQIsdp'` in my `connectionArgs` that gets passed to`mqtt.connect()` or I get `Error: Connection refused: Not authorized` if I leave it out.

**gcloud.js**

```
const fs = require('fs')
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken')
const mqtt = require('mqtt')
const exec = require('child_process').exec

const projectId = 'my-project'
const cloudRegion = 'us-central1'
const registryId = 'my-registry'
const mqttHost = 'mqtt.googleapis.com'
const mqttPort = 8883
const privateKeyFile = './certs/rsa_private.pem'
const algorithm = 'RS256'
var messageType = 'events'// or event

function createJwt (projectId, privateKeyFile, algorithm) {
  var token = {
    iat: parseInt(Date.now() / 1000),
    exp: parseInt(Date.now() / 1000) + 86400 * 60, // 1 day
    aud: projectId
  }
  const privateKey = fs.readFileSync(privateKeyFile)
  return jwt.sign(token, privateKey, {
    algorithm: algorithm
  })
}

function fetchData () {}
async function configureDevice () { 
  // Get the device's serial number
  await exec('cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep Serial', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error) {
      console.error(`exec error: ${error}`)
      return
    }
    // Concat serial number w/ project name to meet device id naming requirement starting w/ a letter 
    const deviceId = `my-project${stdout.split(' ')[1].split('\n')[0]}` 
    var mqttClientId = 'projects/' + projectId + '/locations/' + cloudRegion + '/registries/' + registryId + '/devices/' + deviceId
    var mqttTopic = '/devices/' + deviceId + '/' + messageType
    var connectionArgs = {
      // protocolId: 'MQIsdp' if I add this property I see "connecting..." get logged in the console 
      // followed by "close" repeatedly being logged. If I don't add it I get
      // "Error: Connection refused: Not authorized" 
      host: mqttHost,
      port: mqttPort,
      clientId: mqttClientId,
      username: 'unused',
      password: createJwt(projectId, privateKeyFile, algorithm),
      protocol: 'mqtts',
      secureProtocol: 'TLSv1_2_method'
    }
    console.log('connecting...')
    var client = mqtt.connect(connectionArgs)
    // Subscribe to the /devices/{device-id}/config topic to receive config updates.
    client.subscribe('/devices/' + deviceId + '/config')

    client.on('connect', function (success) {
      if (success) {
        console.log('Client connected...')
        sendData()
      } else {
        console.log('Client not connected...')
      }
    })

    client.on('close', function () {
      debugger
      console.log('close')
    })
     client.on('error', function (err) {
      debugger
      console.log('error', err)
    })

    client.on('message', function (topic, message, packet) {
      console.log(topic, 'message received: ', Buffer.from(message, 'base64').toString('ascii'))
    })

    function sendData () {
      var payload = fetchData()

      payload = JSON.stringify(payload)
      console.log(mqttTopic, ': Publishing message:', payload)
      client.publish(mqttTopic, payload, { qos: 1 })

      console.log('Transmitting in 30 seconds')
      setTimeout(sendData, 30000)
    }
  })
}

configureDevice()
```

Comment: @GabeWeiss any ideas what may be going on? Thanks!

Comment: Are there any Stackdriver log records being recorded corresponding to the connection attempts?  It sounds like GCP is not liking the incoming connection ... perhaps the log records will elaborate on why?

Comment: @Kolban what specifically might get logged in a connection attempt? There are some things in my logs but it mostly seems to pertain to configuration things that I've done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first, just a note on the roots.pem. There's multiple certs in there because the roots.pem is covering itself for if/when Google rotates the authorizing certificate. So it includes a bunch to allow for the roots.pem to be valid for longer, that's all. If you can identify which is the active cert (it changes maybe every three or four months ish?) you can actually delete all the other certs and just leave the one active cert. I had to do that for awhile when I was working on a seriously constrained MC with only 200k space on it. The roots.pem was too big, took up most of my storage on the device. There's more info here: https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/mqtt-bridge#using_a_long-term_mqtt_domain about a long-term domain that we setup to enable using a smaller root cert against a long term domain.

And you don't want/need to add the roots.pem into the registry-level certificate, as that's only needed if you want to use your own certificate authority to validate against new devices being registered. It's a bit confusing, but it doesn't have anything to do with authorizing devices after they're registered, it's about guarding against someone hacking your project and registering their own devices.

As for why the code isn't working: Your JWT is invalid because your expiration tag is: `exp: parseInt(Date.now() / 1000) + 86400 * 60, // 1 day` which is longer than JWTs are valid for. 86400 seconds * 60 is 1,440 hours... JWT's longer than 24 hours are rejected. So that's a bad error message. I mean, it's TECHNICALLY correct because the password is the JWT, and that's invalid, so it's an invalid pw...but it could probably be better. I'll take back to the team, but try changing that 86400 * 60 to just 86400 and it should work.

Per comment below: It was also the device name. Since it was dynamically generated, there was a missed character (dash instead of underscore).

*Old Answer:
As for the rest, I don't see anything blaringly obvious, but what happens if you remove the async/await wrapper, and run it synchronously? Also just verify that your SSL key was created and registered with the same protocol (RSA, with or without the X509 wrapper). I've had issues before with registering one way and have the key actually be the other way.*

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation on the roots.pem. I had added the async/await because the connection requests was getting made before I could get the serial number back from the Raspberry Pi and I was creating my unique device id with undefined concatenated instead of the serial number. I will try running it with the device id directly and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: I got the same behavior when I removed the async/await and passed what was getting concatenated as a string directly. I have `RS256_X509` set as the private key format on the device in IoT Core. This is what I ran in the  command line to generate the public /private key pair `openssl rsa -in rsa_private.pem -pubout -out rsa_public.pem`

Comment: But you didn't run the second piece to wrap it in the X509? That might be the problem. Check this: https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/credentials/keys

Specifically the command should be: openssl req -x509 -nodes -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout rsa_private.pem \
    -out rsa_cert.pem -subj "/CN=unused"

Comment: OR change the device SSL setting to RS256 (no _X509)

Comment: I will have to try regenerating it. When I click `update` it doesn't accept the change to the public key format.

Comment: Hrm, I'm seeing the same. I'll poke our eng folks to see if that's intended, and if we can get some better feedback if it is. As a good test, I'd just register a new device is probably the fastest path (rather than regenerating and re-flashing, etc).

Comment: Yes, definitely let me know. An additional note, I get a message `req: Use -help for summary.` when I try to run the line you've posted for an X509. Running the command for a regular RS256 runs with no issues.

Comment: Oh sorry, cut/paste problems... remove the '\' between `rsa_private.pem` and `-out`

Comment: OK, I'll give that a shot. I didn't register a new device I just updated the certificate to an R256 and received the same error as before.

Comment: Found it (and I'll put this in the answer)... your JWT is invalid because your expiration tag is: `exp: parseInt(Date.now() / 1000) + 86400 * 60, // 1 day` which is longer than JWTs are valid for. 86400 seconds * 60 is 1,440 hours... JWT's longer than 24 hours are rejected. So that's a bad error message that I'll take back to the team, but try changing that 86400 * 60 to just 86400 and it should work.

Comment: I made the change to the JWT exp and tried both with an RS256 and RS256_X509, both with new roots.pem, and still got "Not authorized" errors. Is a X509 required? If so, does or how does the algorithm param change? I tried passing 'RS256_X509' and got an invalid error.

Comment: I ran your code with my change and it worked changing the exp tag. Freshly generated SSL with X509 ssl key pair. Well, not totally your code, I hardcoded the deviceID to one I've got registered, and I stripped out the pieces to send the data and fetching the device ID. Can you confirm that deviceID actually matches the device you've registered? Since you're dynamically generating the deviceID, is it possible that's not lining up?

Comment: X509 is NOT required, no. In terms of the algorithm param for the mqtt connection, no, doesn't change. X509 is just an extra wrapping around the cert itself, the algorithm itself doesn't change (RSA).

Comment: Also, it's not the roots.pem that needed to be new, it was the ssl key/pair itself I suspect is bad. :)

Also JUST to double check, you registered the public key into IoT Core right? Not the private key?

Comment: It was the device name! When I hard coded it when you asked before I wrote it with  a dash where in the Cloud IoT console it has an underscore. Fixed! Thanks for working through this with me @GabeWeiss!