# How to use root CA certificate in google cloud iot

Tags: google-cloud-iot

I develop embedded firmware, that works with google cloud iot. I used this example https://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/x-cube-gcp.html?ecmp=tt9470_gl_link_feb2019&rt=um&id=UM2441 as a base for my firmware. I have a problem in understanding how the firmware should use root CA certification package (this is described here https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/mqtt-bridge#downloading_mqtt_server_certificates). Google suggest to use this package https://pki.goog/roots.pem to connect to mqtt server. But this file is too big for embedded firmware. In the stm32 example smaller file is used, it contents only 2 certificates:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

I have found this 2 certificates in google package https://pki.goog/roots.pem. Does this mean that I can use any certificate from package? And what will happen after updating active certificate in google cloud, as described here [Why won't my Raspberry Pi connect to Google Cloud IoT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59393066/why-wont-my-raspberry-pi-connect-to-google-cloud-iot). I have already faced a problem with connection to cloud for a some days, but now it works ok again.
I saw that google suggest another way for embedded devices (long-term MQTT domain with minimal root CA set), but it requires to do some changes in firmware and it is difficult now for me.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you mentioned that changing the firmware is hard, and that is true, but there isn't a good way other than this because of the rotation of the general root certificate. Even if you trim the currently unused certs from the CA file, once rotation happens, and it happens frequently, it'll break connectivity.

From this page: https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/mqtt-bridge

```
Google's minimal root CA set (<1 KB) for mqtt.2030.ltsapis.goog. The minimal root CA set includes a primary and backup certificate.

This set is for devices with memory constraints, like microcontrollers, and establishes the chain of trust to communicate with Cloud IoT Core only.
Devices with the minimal root CA set communicate with the Cloud IoT Core via long-term support domains.

This set is fixed through 2030 (the primary and backup certificates won't change). For added security, Google Trust Services may switch between the primary and backup certificates at any time without notice.
```

Which is what you need to use for embedded systems that you don't want to deal with rotating certificates every time the core Google root CA rotates certificates. Here are the links for the primary and backup root certs:
https://pki.goog/gtsltsr/gtsltsr.crt
https://pki.goog/gsr4/GSR4.crt

**Note** also that this uses that different endpoint for this certificate. The general (128K) root cert is used when connecting to `mqtt.googleapis.com`, and the smaller long-term support root CA uses `mqtt.2030.ltsapis.goog` so you'll need to change your firmware to account for this.